# Variable ip needed in address field of dnsmasq.conf

Tags: dnsmasq

I have 2 ethernet interfaces eth0 and eth1 which are connected to 2 access points.
my dnsmas.conf

```
 dhcp-range=interface:eth0,192.168.190.5,192.168.190.200,255.255.255.0,24h
 dhcp-range=interface:eth1,192.168.191.5,192.168.191.200,255.255.255.0,24h
 bind-interfaces
 port=53
 address=/#/192.168.190.1
 expand-hosts
 domain-needed
 bogus-priv
```

I am using this **address=/#/192.168.190.1** for captive portal popup in mobiles. But here I have 2 ip addresses ,the **address** fields allowing only single ip.

Is there any way that I can use ip dynamically depending on client request

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a bridge where eth0 and eth1 are members, and then use the bridge interface for the L3 traffic.

This way the bridge interface has a single IP address.